# how to set different ids for different estimote beacons?

Tags: android, ibeacon, estimote

Suppose, Android app is detecting 3 beacons with in range with default UUID value.  So, how can i set/change the name for each beacons in Anndroid (to identify each beacon)?

Appreciations for any suggestions... Thanks

Comment: You have to create a beacon broadcast receiver and then you can get mac address of the broadcasted beacon and then you can compare it with 3 Mac addresses you have so that you can open respective activity you can get the sample with estimote beacons :)

Comment: ur welcome, you got the solution?

Comment: Can you provide any example with Source code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need estimote sdk 
Then you can create a beaconDetection service something like this

```
public class BeaconMyService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "BeaconMyService";

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION = new Region("rid", null, null, null);

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        if (beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled())
        {

            connectToService();
        }
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    private void connectToService()
    {
        beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady()
            {
                try
                {
                    beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION);
                }
                catch (RemoteException e)
                {
                    Log.e("Myservice", "Cannot start ranging, something terrible happened");
                    Log.e("", "Cannot start ranging", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons)
            {

                // Note that beacons reported here are already sorted by
                // estimated
                // distance between device and beacon.
                for (int index = 0; index < beacons.size(); index++)
                {
                    Beacon beacon = beacons.get(index);

                    if (beacon != null)
                    {
                        Log.v("Beacon MacAddress", beacon.getMacAddress() + "");
                        if (!Constants.BEACONSDETECTEDLIST.containsKey(beacon.getMacAddress()))
                        {//Constants.BEACONSDETECTEDLIST is your list of beacon mac addresses
                    //public static HashMap<String, Long> BEACONSDETECTEDLIST = new HashMap<String, Long>(); 
                        //to check if beacon is detected for the first time

                            if (Constants.BEACON1.equalsIgnoreCase(beacon.getMacAddress()))
                            {//Constants.BEACON1 is mac address of beacon 1 assigned in constants
                                Constants.BEACONSDETECTEDLIST.put(beacon.getMacAddress(), System.currentTimeMillis());
                                handler.postDelayed(beacon1Detection, 2000);
                            }
                            else if (Constants.BEACON2.equalsIgnoreCase(beacon.getMacAddress()))
                            {
                                Constants.BEACONSDETECTEDLIST.put(beacon.getMacAddress(), System.currentTimeMillis());
                                handler.postDelayed(beacon2Detection, 2000);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {/*Do Nothing*/
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private Runnable beacon1Detection = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {

            beacon1Info();
        }
    };

    private Runnable beacon2Detection = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {

            beacon2Info();
        }
    };

    private void beacon1Info()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.BEACON1BROADCAST_ACTION);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }//in Constants 
    //public static final String BEACON1BROADCAST_ACTION = "beacon1Action";



    private void beacon2Info()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.BEACON2BROADCAST_ACTION);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }// in Constants
    //public static final String BEACON2BROADCAST_ACTION = "beacon2Action";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        handler.removeCallbacks(beacon1Detection);
        handler.removeCallbacks(beacon2Detection);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And then finally you need a BeaconBroadcastReceiver to receive the broadcasts in the service and open respective Activity

```
public class BeaconBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.BEACON1BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, Beacon1Layout.class);
                context.startActivity(intent2);

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.BEACON2BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, Beacon2Layout.class);
                context.startActivity(intent2);

            }
        }

    }
```

Hope this will help you, Good luck :)

Comment: Welcome, Did you try it? did it worked for you? If yes please accept this as an answer, thanks :)

Comment: Yha, its worked for me. I used the same with notifications instead of Broadcast message and Please let me know how to accept this answer.

Comment: Thats great, You will see a tick on left side of my answer you need to check it :)

Comment: Did my answer helped you or you found out a different way ??

Comment: I did it. And, Let me know Is it possible to show the beacons location and the directions to the user in Android app.

Comment: You can post your own answer too, it might help others, so please post your way too, I have not came across such, i know that distance can be calculated as estimote sample app shows that I dont know about direction and location sorry :(

Comment: Ok, Any way Thanking you for quick responses. And,Sure I'll post my  solutions as per my requirement.

Comment: Yes that would be great as I am interested in knowing beacons thing better :) and you seem to be very interested in that :)

Answer (score 1):

Beacons are identified not only by UUID, but also by their [major](http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/Beacon.html#getMajor()) and [minor](http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/Beacon.html#getMinor()) values, and this whole set (UUID + Major + Minor) is how you can differentiate between them.

Moreover, these values are hierarchical in nature, which allows you to put some structure into your beacon deployment. Consider this example:

- Whole Museum: UUID = B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D

  - North Wing: Major = 1

    - Exhibit A: Minor = 1
    - Exhibit B: Minor = 2
  - South Wing: Major = 2

This way, when your device comes in range of a beacon B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D:1:2, just by looking at it you'll know that it's at the North Wing, Exhibit B.

Comment: How can we do this in Android Programatically can you provide any example with Source code, please. If i'm near to a beacon I want to display in Android App like **"1"**, if i'm near to 3rd beacon i want to show **"3"** to the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
this is i got a solution to set different ids for different beacons. and also identifying differnet beacons and sending notifications to the user when app not in foreground.

I initially confused where to change Major and Minor values of beacons.

Simply, i installed Estimote Android app from Playstore 
here, 
1. Click on Beacons
2. Select one beacon and it displays one more detailed activity in that you can change Values (for me i changed Minor values for all beacon based on my requirement).

So, now Minor values for all beacons changed as per your requirement. After that find the below code

In this below code I am sending notification if App is in background or else i am dirctly updating statuses in Activity main class.

I changed Beacons values as 1,2,3,4. 


public class BeaconMyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "BeaconMyService";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION = new Region("rid",
            null, null, null);

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 123;

    private Messenger messageHandler;
    Bundle extras;

    private String notifyMsg ="";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            extras = intent.getExtras();
            messageHandler = (Messenger) extras.get("MESSENGER");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Called=============");
        if (beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled()) {

            connectToService();
        }
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    private void connectToService() {
        beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                try {
                    beaconManager.startRanging(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS_REGION);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    Log.e("Myservice",
                            "Cannot start ranging, something terrible happened");
                    Log.e("", "Cannot start ranging", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);

        beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region,
                    final List<Beacon> beacons) {

                // Note that beacons reported here are already sorted by
                // estimated
                // distance between device and beacon.
                for (int index = 0; index < beacons.size(); index++) {
                    Beacon beacon = beacons.get(index);

                    if (beacon != null) {

                        if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                            if (Utils.computeAccuracy(beacons.get(0)) < 1.0) {
                                try {
                                    switch (beacons.get(0).getMinor()) {
                                    case 1:
                                        if (isAppInForeground(getApplicationContext())) {
                                            Message message = Message.obtain();
                                            message.arg1 = beacons.get(0)
                                                    .getMinor();
                                            try {
                                                messageHandler.send(message);
                                            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            postNotification(beacons.get(0)
                                                    .getMinor()
                                                    + ". Welcome to Media Lab");
                                        }

                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        if (isAppInForeground(getApplicationContext())) {
                                            Message message = Message.obtain();
                                            message.arg1 = beacons.get(0)
                                                    .getMinor();
                                            try {
                                                messageHandler.send(message);
                                            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            postNotification(beacons.get(0)
                                                    .getMinor()
                                                    + ". Welcome to Gaming Zone");
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                        if (isAppInForeground(getApplicationContext())) {
                                            Message message = Message.obtain();
                                            message.arg1 = beacons.get(0)
                                                    .getMinor();
                                            try {
                                                messageHandler.send(message);
                                            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            postNotification(beacons.get(0)
                                                    .getMinor()
                                                    + ". Welcome to eLearing Education");
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case 4:
                                        if (isAppInForeground(getApplicationContext())) {
                                            Message message = Message.obtain();
                                            message.arg1 = beacons.get(0)
                                                    .getMinor();
                                            try {
                                                messageHandler.send(message);
                                            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            postNotification(beacons.get(0)
                                                    .getMinor()
                                                    + ". Welcome to Retail Department");
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    // TODO: handle exception
                                }
                            }else{

                                if (isAppInForeground(getApplicationContext())) {
                                    Message message = Message.obtain();
                                    message.arg1 = 10;
                                    try {
                                        messageHandler.send(message);
                                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }

//                              Utils.computeAccuracy(beacons.get(0))
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // ---helper method to determine if the app is in
    // the foreground---
    public static boolean isAppInForeground(Context context) {
        List<RunningTaskInfo> task = ((ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getRunningTasks(1);
        if (task.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        Log.e(TAG + "isAppInForeground-----",
                ""
                        + task.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName()));

        return task.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                context.getPackageName());
    }

    private void postNotification(String msg) {
        if(!notifyMsg.equalsIgnoreCase(msg)){
            notifyMsg = msg;
            Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(BeaconMyService.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            notifyIntent.putExtra("content", msg);

            notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(
                    BeaconMyService.this, 0, new Intent[] { notifyIntent },
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(
                    BeaconMyService.this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Monitoring Region").setContentText(msg)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }

    }

}


Coming to Activity for updating status is this

package com.hcl.beacons_notification_ex;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static TextView tv_items;
    public static Handler messageHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv_items = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_items);
        messageHandler = new MessageHandler();
    }

    public static class MessageHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            int state = message.arg1;
            switch (state) {
            case 1:
                tv_items.setText("Welcome to Media Lab");
                break;
            case 2:
                tv_items.setText("Welcome to Gaming Zone");
                break;
            case 3:
                tv_items.setText("Welcome to eLearing Education");
                break;
            case 4:
                tv_items.setText("Welcome to Retail Department");
                break;
            default:
                tv_items.setText("Going far to Range");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BeaconMyService.class);
        if(isMyServiceRunning(BeaconMyService.class)){

        }else{
            i.putExtra("MESSENGER", new Messenger(messageHandler));
            startService(i);
//          startService(i);
        }

        try {
            if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                tv_items.setText(""
                        + getIntent().getExtras().getString("content"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```